# How do I create a progress bar container that fills based on my data?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget(s) to build that looks like this:

[image]

Being somewhat new to flutter, I'm drawing a blank on how to achieve the background being filled like that.

I do have my data like so:

```dart
enum ProgressKeys {
  articles,
  meals,
  bloodPressure,
  mood,
  physicalActivity,
  weight,
}

class StepProgress {
  StepProgress({
    required this.displayText,
    required this.progress,
    required this.count,
  });

  final String displayText;
  final int progress;
  int count;
}

final Map<ProgressKeys, StepProgress> programStepCounts = {
  ProgressKeys.articles: {
    displayText: "Articles Read",
    progress: 2,
    count: 4,
  },
  ProgressKeys.meals: {
    displayText: "Meals Logged",
    progress: 3,
    count: 9,
  },
  // Etc...
}
```

All I can think of is start with a `ListView.builder` but I have no idea how to achieve something like this with the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LinearProgressIndicator` inside a Stack! Heres a code sample:

```
return Center(
  child: Container(
    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
    ),
    height: 80.0,
    width: double.infinity,
    child: Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      children: [
        Positioned.fill(
          child: LinearProgressIndicator(
            //Here you pass the percentage
            value: 0.7,
            color: Colors.blue.withAlpha(100),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(50),
          ),
        ),
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
          child: Text('Hello world'),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

You can pass to `LinearProgressIndicator` a value between 0 to 1 wich represents the percentage of completition. In the code sample i used 0.7 so its 70% full. It looks like this:

[image: Code example]

Of course you can change the colors and in the first container you can adjust the border.

Comment: Wow what! I came across `LinearProgressIndicator` and had no idea this was even possible with it. Thank you!